# Java: Converting from .NET Constructors

Tags: java, .net, constructor

We're converting some .NET 3.5 code to Java (Android).

This Java code gives the error:

*Syntax error on token "Chapters", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token*

```
this.add (new Book() {Chapters=50, OneBasedBookID = 1, 
Long = "Bahai", Short = "ba", Color = c,   BookType = b; });
```

The types are all correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't have [object initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), so this syntax is not valid.

Instead, you're probably looking to do something like this:

```
Book book = new Book();

book.Chapters = 50;
book.OneBasedBookID = 1;
book.Long = "Bahai";
book.Short = "ba";
book.Color = c;
book.BookType = b;

this.add(book);
```

Also note that Java has no concept of ["proper" properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04%28VS.80%29.aspx) either, and typical "good" practice is to use getters/setters, and to not name your variables starting with upper-case letters. This wouldn't work for your `Long` and `Short` members though, and overall these practices may not provide any value in your scenario anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You are using .NET/C#'s ability to initialize properties at the time you create your object. To do it in Java (or in older C#), you are going to have to do it the long way.

```
Book book = new Book();
book.Chapters = 50;
// etc
this.add(book);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the anonymous class initializer trick:

```
this.add (new Book() {{
    Chapters=50;
    OneBasedBookID = 1;
    Long = "Bahai";
    Short = "ba";
    Color = c;
    BookType = b;
}});
```

Comment: (+1) I'm not sure about creating the anonymous class just for this purpose, and it does require that you declare `c` and `b` to be final, but this is an interesting approach (and has the benefit of matching the OP's desired syntax closely).

Comment: @Loius - Yeah, it's similar to delcaring a non-static inner class, and then assigning values to the enclosing type's members. You end up with an anonymous type though, not an actual `Book`.